# Remove shadow below actionbar FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android, pagerslidingtabstrip

Still can't remove the shadow below the actionbar.
I am using SlidingTabLayout, SlidingTabStrip, and FragmentActivity.

I already tried this:

```
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable();
```

and in SlidingTabLayout:

```
tabTitleView.setTextColor(); 
tabTitleView.setBackgroundColor();
```

However, when setting the background color in `tabTitleView` the shadow is gone but I don't see the indicator color anymore.

Comment: may be you have android:foreground="?android:windowContentOverlay" attribute in child view?

Comment: Nope didn't got that in any of my views..

Comment: Does it has the shadow on lollipop devices? And actionbar or toolbar?

Comment: Didn't tried toolbar out yet but I a, testing on lollipop device (nexus 5)

Comment: ok, may be you should set ab elevation to 0dp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I found solution on the reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2cgbux/material_design_turn_off_action_bar_elevation/), you should to set windowContentOverlay to @null by defauld in your style.xml

[Or try this method from Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setElevation(float)) to your action bar